# Can you help in making visual studio ssh connect to a remote computer?

Tags: linux, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, ssh, macos-catalina

Remote ssh connection used to work really well on my macOS 10.15 Catalina. But I just did a security update and visual studio cannot ssh connect to remote computers any more.
I double checked the config files and everything looks good. ssh-key login  works fine when I connect via terminal.
I tried to share output from the console when it disconnected, but visual studio is not letting me copy-paste it and gives errors. Can anyone please help me?
Version: 1.56.0 (Universal)
Commit: cfa2e218100323074ac1948c885448fdf4de2a7f
Date: 2021-05-04T22:06:21.189Z
Electron: 12.0.4
Chrome: 89.0.4389.114
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 8.9.255.24-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 19.6.0

````
Output from VS console when it cannot ssh connect:
[19:25:52.267] Using commit id "cfa2e218100323074ac1948c885448fdf4de2a7f" and quality "stable" for server
[19:25:52.311] Install and start server if needed
[19:25:54.515] getPlatformForHost was canceled
[19:25:54.515] Resolver error: Error: Connecting was canceled```
````

Comment: I installed a previous version of VS and everything started working again. I am interested in knowing if these kinds of issues are very common. I wonder why these bugs are present in one of the most popular IDEs!!

Comment: if you use VS why tag it with VSC, 1.56 is the latest VSC, I'm confused